# insert into select inserting current date instead of selected date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data in **bill_transaction** table from **temp_table** using below query.

```
INSERT INTO bill_transaction (bill_number, bill_amount, bill_date)
SELECT bill_number, bill_amount, bill_date FROM temp_table
```

in **temp_table** and **bill_transaction** table there is **bill_date** column but in **bill_transaction** table the **bill_date** data_type is **timestamp**.
When data is inserting into **bill_transaction** table. bill_date is inserting as the current date and time, but it should be same like **temp_table** bill_date.

```
CREATE TABLE bill_transaction ( 
   id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   bill_number VARCHAR(255) NULL, 
   bill_date TIMESTAMP,
   bill_amount VARCHAR(255) NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: is there any default value assigned for bill_date column in bill_transaction  table

Comment: no, only datatype is TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Can you publish your table definitions please.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `bill_transaction` (
              id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              bill_number VARCHAR(255) NULL,
              bill_date TIMESTAMP,
              bill_amount VARCHAR(255) NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (id)

Comment: A simple insert won't do as you have observed - are there any triggers on bill_transaction?

Comment: Please add this info directly in our question as this is essential info (I did for you). I dont see a `bill_date` column in your CREATE TABLE statement. Explain. Also check if you have any  TRIGGERS that could change the `bill_date`

Comment: is there a reason for default value. as i have checked in actual phpmyadmin there is a default value **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** ?

Comment: Then your table definition is probably not what you thing it is - can you execute show create table bill_transaction and edit the code in the question if appropriate. Even if the default is set to current_timestamp you won't get the result you observe given what you say you have done.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Try: INSERT INTO bill_transaction (bill_number, bill_amount, bill_date)
SELECT bill_number, bill_amount, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bill_date) FROM temp_table

Comment: I tracked the issue, it was comming from **temp_table**, sometimes it was returning null value for bill_date(after importing from xlsx file).